# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity not work on Razor Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a simple solution composed of two project:

1. ASP.NET Core main project
2. Razor class library

I would like to use IdentityRole inside razor class library, so I downloaded Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity inside my razor class library project and when I write

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace RazorClassLibrary2.MyFeature.Pages
{
  public class Page1Model : PageModel
  {
      public void OnGet()
      {
          IdentityRole role;
      }
   }
}
```

I get the following error:

> the type or namespace name 'IdentityRole' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Since I want to use .Net Core framework but Razor Class Library are created with

```
<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
```

I change it with

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
```

> note: change TargetFramework seems ok, see this comment
>   https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/7816#issuecomment-428193831

Thinking that this manipulation could be the cause of the problem, I create another **"project > Class Library (.Net Core)"**, downloaded Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity, and create another class like

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
       IdentityRole role;
    }
}
```

if I download Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity inside ASP.NET Core (main) project and declare a variable of type IdentityRole inside any class of main project, then the reference is found.

Where am I going wrong?

You can find a sample project here https://github.com/Blackleones/identityTest feel free to send pull request if you want collaborate.

Answer (score 1):

I solved adding **microsoft.aspnetcore.app** package to razor class library project.
The problem was that IdentityRole is defined inside **microsoft.extensions.identity.core** and this package is not a dependency of **microsoft.aspnetcore.identity**